# How play default CLICK sound with delphi on android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-audiomanager

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Media, Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, AndroidApi.Jni.JavaTypes, AndroidApi.Jni.App;

procedure Sound;
var
AudioObj: JObject;
Audio: JAudioManager;

begin
AudioObj:= TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(
    TJActivity.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE);
Audio := TJAudioManager.Wrap((AudioObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
Audio.loadSoundEffects;
Audio.playSoundEffect(0);
//0 - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants.html

end;
```

How i can play **system default sound** on Android?
CLICK, NAVIGATION_DOWN, NAVIGATION_LEFT, NAVIGATION_RIGHT, NAVIGATION_UP

I do not wont add **my** mp3 file to App.

Comment: I need standart sound from Android (no deployment)

Comment: this is not a duplicate